# How to check tron’s usdt balance?

Tags: blockchain, tron

How to check my usdt balance using javascript? My account balance is 0, why is 150990000 output? What is uint256?The address is my wallet, no problem

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    owner_address: 'TUhycsR2geBGknpwqTz3n7i63XqPUWLJjR',
    contract_address: 'TXYZopYRdj2D9XRtbG411XZZ3kM5VkAeBf',
    function_selector: 'balanceOf(address)',
    parameter: '000000000000000000000000a614f803b6fd780986a42c78ec9c7f77e6ded13c',
    visible: true
  })
};
fetch(' https://nile.trongrid.io/wallet/triggerconstantcontract', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    async function ff(){
      console.log(response)
    let outputs = '0x'+response.constant_result[0]

    let result =  await decodeParams(['uint256'], outputs, false)

    console.log(result[0].toNumber())

    }
    ff();
    
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my getTRC20TokenBalance function, I hope it works for you:

```
import TronWeb from 'tronweb';
const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: 'https://api.trongrid.io',
    solidityNode: 'https://api.trongrid.io',
    eventServer: 'https://api.trongrid.io',
})
tronWeb.setAddress('TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t');

const tokenContractAddress = 'TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t'
const accountAddress = 'TJCxtgAMgVJ4E4ryzYsmMzD6qdJeDnZPHe'

const getTRC20TokenBalance = async (contractAddress, account) => {
    try {
        const accountHex = tronWeb.address.toHex(account)
        const contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contractAddress)
        const balance = await contract.balanceOf(accountHex).call()
        return tronWeb.toDecimal(balance._hex)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al obtener el balance de USDT:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export async function GET(request) {
    const balance = await getTRC20TokenBalance(tokenContractAddress, accountAddress)
    return new Response(balance / 1000000, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing 150990000 instead of 0 could be due to the token's decimals. Many tokens use 18 decimals, so you need to divide the result by 10**18 to get the actual balance. If your token uses a different number of decimals, you'll need to adjust this accordingly.

Here's how you can do this:

```
console.log(result[0].dividedBy(10**18).toNumber());
```

This will give you the balance in the base unit of the token.